# Google Script - isDate function & Optimization - looking for a different approach than for loop

Tags: loops, date, validation, google-apps-script

- I have a couple of columns with each different type of data for each row (person). so for example column 1 (A) contains names, column 2 (B) contains the amount of points and column 3 contains a date set by the user (if not, it's empty).
- The first problem I have is validating the input for setting a date in the sheet. right now it just pastes anything  in there, So I made a workaround:

```
  
      var input = (request.parameter.input || "");
      ss.getRange("I1").setValue(input); //input given by user using text
      var isdate = ss.getRange("J1").getDisplayValue(); //J1 contains a formula "=isDATE(I1)"
      if(isdate == "TRUE"){ ss.getRange(position + 2, 3, 1, 1).setValue(input);}
```

- However, this is not really efficient. but I can't seem to make it work.
- The second problem is where I want to loop over all rows to see if that date corresponds with the date today (so if it would be their birthday) and have them being pushed on a String, and then return the string in the end.

  ```
      var input = (request.parameter.input || "");
      var output = ContentService.createTextOutput;

      var users = ss.getRange("A2:A").getValues().filter(String);
      var points = ss.getRange("B2:B").getValues().filter(String);
      var birthdays = ss.getRange("C2:C").getValues();
      var list = [];

      function isBirthdayToday(birthday) {
        if(typeof birthday === "string"){ birthday = new Date(birthday);} 
        var today = new Date();
        if((today.getDate() === birthday.getDate()) && (today.getMonth() === birthday.getMonth())) {
          return true;
        } 
        else {
          return false;
        }
      }

      for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
        var date = ss.getRange(i + 2, 3, 1, 1).getValue();
        if(isBirthdayToday(date)){
          var name = ss.getRange(i + 2, 1, 1, 1).getValue();
          list.push(name);
        } 
      }
      return output(list) //return all names
  ```
- I do believe there must be a more efficient way of doing this.

Comment: For your first question, I did not fully understood how the date inputs were obtained? It seems it is not updated in the sheets directly.Another thing for your 2nd concern, I'm not sure if you are using a custom formula or what since the code snippet is not that clear. I didn't fully understood the return output(list) part. I would appreciate if you could provide a sample sheet containing your current code. [Share a test sheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383)

Comment: It would be best if you could also provide a sample input and an expected output

Comment: @RonM So basically I get input via a browser. and also the output will be outputted in the browser when someone calls this function. and I want it to show who's bday it is for all people that given us a date.

the input is obtained like: 
var input = (request.parameter.input || "")
var output = ContentService.createTextOutput;

I have updated the text above.

Comment: To be honest, I cannot visualize your complete code implementation, design and output. Hence, I cannot provide where it could be optimized

Comment: Is your date input either a valid date or an empty input? It seems you are using a webapp. I would appreciate if you could share a sample screenshot of your sheet data (just a sample data, remove sensitive information) foe me to fully understood your ranges used

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have now created an Array containing the names of the people of that are having their birthday today.

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
var data = ss.getDataRange().offset(0, 2, ss.getLastRow(), ss.getLastColumn() - 2).getValues();

var BirthNames = [];
    data.filter(function getBirthNames(row){
    let birthDate = new Date(row[4]);  // the position in the data array that includes birthdays.
    let today = new Date();
    if ((birthDate.getDate() == today.getDate())&&(birthDate.getMonth() == today.getMonth())){
        BirthNames.push(" "+row[0]);  // the position in the data array that includes names.        
    };
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can search for birthday boys/girls using the following code

```
function getBirthNames(){
  let sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName(-- here is your sheet name --),
      values = sheet.getDataRange().getValues(),
      today = new Date();
  return values.reduce((resArr,element)=>{
    let elementDate = new Date(element[2]);   // column C with birthdays 
    if (elementDate.getDate()==today.getDate() && elementDate.getMonth()==today.getMonth()){
      resArr.push(element[0])                 // column A with names
    };
    return resArr},[])
}
```